# How to load a subdirectory inside resources folder using -Dloader.path?

Tags: spring-boot, classloader, bootloader, bootclasspath

The folder created inside jar is BOOT-INF/classes/global/DEV. Now I'm running the application with below command which is not loading the properties files inside DEV folder.
java -Dloader.path=/BOOT-INF/classes/global/DEV -jar demo.jar.

Tried with BOOT-INF/classes/global/DEV, BOOT-INF/classes/global/DEV/*, BOOT-INF/classes/global/DEV/**,
/global/DEV, /global/DEV/, /resources/global/DEV etc..

Just to note: application.properties is getting loaded fine which is a sibling of resources/DEV folder. Also I tried with @PropertySource annotation which works fine for the files inside DEV folder where I need to specify each and every files .But that also I can't use since PropertySource does not support XML files and I have some XML files present inside DEV folder.
That's why I want some way to load the DEV directory in the classpath using loader.path or with some other JVM argument